# Error Install Matplotlib for Python3 on Debian 9

Tags: python, linux, bash, matplotlib, debian

I'm trying to install MatPlotLib for Python3 using Debian 8. The `pip3`
command asks for the missing dependency: libfreetype. However, this is what happens when I try to install this package!

```
debnub@debhub:~$ sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libfreetype6-dev : Depends: libfreetype6 (= 2.5.2-3+deb8u2) but 2.
6.3-3.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
debnub@debhub:~$
```

I've tried a lot of different solutions including using aptitude. Is there anything I might be missing in this case?

Comment: It's mostly python related, I just need to use pyplot, normally pip3 works but in this case I'm missing dependencies

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by running:

```
sudo aptitude -f install libfreetype6-dev
```

And then selecting `no` to downgrade the installed version of libfreetype6.